# For Nlog, If I have two error level email type config, how to choose which specified email config when I used logger.Error("xxx")？

Tags: c#, nlog

I have two type error in my program,when _logger.Error("xxx"), and the first error type I want send email to A(configured in nlog.config)  ,and the second type I want send email to B, how to do it ?

```
<target name="A" xsi:type="Mail" from="" to="" subject="" smtpServer="" smtpPort="0" skipCertificateValidation="true">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
        <attribute name="text" layout="${message}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="fileName" layout="${var:fileName}"/>
        <attribute name="logGroupName" layout="${var:logGroupName}"/>
        <attribute name="logStreamName" layout="${var:logStreamName}"/>
        <attribute name="category" layout="${logger}" />
        <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=@}" encode="false"/>
      </layout>
    </target>

<target name="B" xsi:type="Mail" from="" to="" subject="" smtpServer="" smtpPort="0" skipCertificateValidation="true">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
    <attribute name="text" layout="${message}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
    <attribute name="fileName" layout="${var:fileName}"/>
    <attribute name="logGroupName" layout="${var:logGroupName}"/>
    <attribute name="logStreamName" layout="${var:logStreamName}"/>
    <attribute name="category" layout="${logger}" />
    <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=@}" encode="false"/>
  </layout>
</target>
```

Comment: This could be helpful: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Answer (score 1):

You would introduce two rules with `name` attribute set to logger names that won't appear anywhere else. We usually create loggers with `GetCurrentClassLogger`, so they are named after the classes they are created in. So, you name these two to something that can't possibly be a class from your project. And you set `final="true"` for them:

```
<rules>
   <logger name="MailerA" minlevel="Info" writeTo="A" final="true" />
   <logger name="MailerB" minlevel="Info" writeTo="B" final="true" />
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logFile" /> <!-- if you have it -->
</rules>
```

And in your code you create loggers with specified names and use them when you want to send email to specified targets:

```
Logger mailerA = LogManager.GetLogger("MailerA");
Logger mailerB = LogManager.GetLogger("MailerB");

mailerA.Error("xxx");
mailerB.Error("yyy");
```